# How to communicate between Qt application and MFC application?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have two dialogs. One is created by Qt, another is created by MFC. Qt dialog generates data and MFC dialog gets the generated data and draws them. Now the problem is how to send the data from Qt to MFC.

My thought is as follows：

1. In Qt, use QSharedMemory.
2. In MFC, use OpenFileMapping() and MapViewOfFile().

But the problem is QSharedMemory has the member function lock() and unlock() to control the synchronization. But in MFC, I do not know how to use the synchronization(CreateMutex or other??)?

I hope you can tell me the detailed code about the synchronization in MFC. Thank you!

Comment: I can see you're new to StackOverflow so I highly suggest reading this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Have you made any attempts at this so far?

Comment: Use same Win32 API code on both sides and never get to specifics of each framework then.